# GAN нейросеть - меняется шум, но показания прежние. Как это возможно?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Играюсь с нейросетью из туториала гугла 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Этапы построения

1)Подготавливаем выборку изображений

2)Делаем генератор (вход - много нейронов(7x7x256), выход - 1 изображения размером 28 на 28 в оттенках серого от -1 до 1)

3)Делаем дискриминатор - на вход - изображение размером 28 на 28 в оттенках серого, выход - цифра-вердикт, 
если 1, то изображение 100% истинно и, если 0, то изображение точно фейк.

4)Запускаем тренировку:

Скармливаем случайный шум генератору

Генератор выдает картинку

Дискриминатор смотрит что это за картинка и выносит свой вердикт(допустим 0.1)

Дискриминатор смотрит на идеальные картинки и выносит свой вердикт

Высчитываем ошибку генератора (она равна кросс-энтропии между правильным ответом дискриминатора на идеальную картинку( т.е. единице) и тем, как оценил дискриминатор нашу картинку(0.1)

Высчитываем ошибку дискриминатора(она равна кросс энтропии между единицей и тем, как дискриминатор оценил идеальные картинки плюс кросс энтропия между нулем и тем как дискриминатор оценил неправильные картинки)

Применяем этим ошибки для обучения наших моделей

```
    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, createGenerator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, createGenerator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    `
```

Повторяем раз за разом.

Вопросы

1)Правильно ли я понял алгоритм работы генеративно-состязательной сети?

2)Почему первых нейронов у генератора на входе так много? Почему 7х7х256? 256 - это BATCH_SIZE, использовалось при подготовке образцов. Но зачем умножать еще на 7х7?

```
 model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100, )))
```

3)Каждый раз в итерации обучения входной шум меняется! Причем случайно! При обучении модели мы добавляем в неё градиенты, основанные на ошибках, но если входные данные все время случайны - разве может мы получать правильные ответы? Сеть работает, и после 50 итераций цифры похожи на цифры, но почему не мешает случайный шум?

````
noise = random.normal([256, 100])

    with GradientTape() as gen_tape, GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      # получаем изображения от генератора изображений, передавая туда шум.
      generated_images = createGenerator(noise, training=True)
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую ответить на некоторые из ваших вопросов.

1. Вы правильно описали этапы построения модели, но описали ее для случая когда BATCH_SIZE = 1. За один шаг генератор создаёт `BATCH_SIZE` картинок из белого шума, а дискриминатор высчитывает ошибку для `BATCH_SIZE` фейковых картинок созданных генератором и для `BATCH_SIZE` реальных картинок и суммирует ошибку.
2. `"Почему 7х7х256?"` 256 - в данном случае это глубина первого слоя. Даже если бы изменили `BATCH_SIZE` - мы не должны были бы менять глубину входного тензора. Размерность первого слоя подбирается таким образом, чтобы получить на выходе правильныё размер тензора с созданными картинками после всех слоев развёртки (deconvolution / transpose convolution) . Т.е. размерность первого слоя зависит от размерности генерируемой картинки и от количества слоёв развёртки - чем больше слоёв тем глубже должна быть размерность вначале.
3. Если на вход генератору подавать одни и те же данные, то он и научится создавать одинаковые картинки и только для данных входных данных. Случайный шум помогает обучать и генератор и дискриминатор. Генератор учится создавать картинки более похожие на исходные реальные картинки, а дискриминатор обучается отличать все более качественные фейки от реальных картинок.

   ---

**Другой пример DCGAN архитектуры:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для простоты описываем этапы для **одной** картинки. В реальном случае это будут тензоры с дополнительной размерностью - `batch_size`, т.е. число картинок обрабатывающихся за один шаг работы сети / модели.

**Генератор**

1. На вход полносвязному слою подается вектор из 100 случайных чисел, на выходе тензор размерности `4x4x1024`
2. На вход развёрточному слою подаётся тензор размерности `4x4x1024`. После слоя развёртки получаем тензор размерности `8x8x512`, т.е. размерность картики увеличилась вдвое, а глубина уменьшилась вдвое.
3. продолжаем развёртку: `8x8x512` --> `16x16x256`
4. продолжаем развёртку: `16x16x256` --> `32x32x128`
5. последний развёрточный слой создаёт картинку нужной нам размерности и глубины (в данном случае с одним цветовым каналом - оттенки серого)

**Дискриминатор**

1. На вход сверточного слоя получаем картинку размерности `64x64x1`, на выходе тензор размерности `32x32x64`
2. свёрточный слой: `32x32x64` --> `16x16x128`
3. свёрточный слой: `16x16x128` --> `8x8x256`
4. свёрточный слой: `8x8x256` --> `4x4x512`
5. полносвязный слой: `4x4x512` --> `1` (вероятность того, что картинка реальная)

---

Таким образом размерность тензора для первого разверточного слоя генератора подбирают так, чтобы после всех слоёв развертки получить картинку нужной размерности (в описанном выше случае - `64x64x1`).